# Cannot read in dvd

Tags: windows, windows-vista

I am using windows vista. I am trying to install a set of dvd's but I keep getting error message 103 "Unable to transfer install.ins to temporary drive with 235k available. Make sure install.ex$ is on source drive" What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do is a "flat copy" of the DVD. Basically you copy the entire dvd to a folder on your desktop or other location on your HDD.

If the copy succeeds then install from the newly created folder.

If the copy fails then try the media in another computer to rule out bad media.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities:

- Bad DVD media (bad dvd and discs do not work in any computer?)
- DVD Drive itself is failing (Do the dvd's work on other computers?)

Either way, it is having trouble reading the disc information and erroring out trying to read a certain file. Try simple stuff first like making sure the dvd's are clean and try the dvds on another computer, before making conclusions. Have you used the discs successfully before?

Comment: This is new computer and I have read other dvd's into it. I do not have another computer to try it on.

Comment: I would start looking at the dvd media itself then. Is it one disc or multiple discs? Have you used the dvd's before on another computer in the past?